# ionicframework and slider update: lazy image are not "loaded" on update slider item order

Tags: ionic-framework

in my ionicframework app I have these items (ng-repeat) where each item has a slider with lazy load image (it's functionality
 from the plugin at the base of ion-slides):

```
<div class="listaImmobili" style="" ng-repeat="item in listaImmobili track by $index">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="box-info">
                        <div class="description" style="">
                            <a href="#/app/immobili/vedi/{{item.ID}}">
                                <ion-slides options="sliderOption" slider="data.slider">
                                    <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="img in item.ImmagineImmobile">
                                        <img class="swiper-lazy" data-src="{{img.ImmagineUrl}} ">
                                    </ion-slide-page>
                                </ion-slides>
                            </a>
....
```

All works when the view is loaded the first time. The first image of each ion-item is loaded and others are loaded only when request (swipe left).

Now: in this view there is a button where user can change the order of listaImmobili (ng-repeat). I can change the order but "new" sliders does not show the first image anymore. If I swipe the image element (of one the ion-items) the first image (of this ion-item) becomes visible.

How can I rerun the lazy functionality when the order change ? 
Or how can I reload the entire page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: add a

```
ng-if="visualizza"
```

to the div container and before starting the reoder use this line in your function

```
$scope.visualizza = false;
```

and after the reoder finish add

```
$scope.visualizza = true;
```

or add it before end of your function.

Does not use ng-show. You need to recreate the HTML and ng-if do it.